# Blazor Hybrid App - Devices and Web deployment

Tags: .net, blazor, maui

I want to start a new project and I'm planning to use Blazor Hybrid App (.Net MAUI + Blazor).

My main question is, can I "extract" the Blazor App to deploy it as a normal Website?

I would like to have just one project and deploy it as a WebApplication + Devices Native Apps.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: In .NET MAUI a BlazorWebView component is added, which can run full Blazor code, including CSS and the JavaScript interop (so it can even run all kinds of JavaScript components). MAUI Blazor Hybrid app is based on the MAUI and this is why it can be run as an application on the mobile device. The BlazorWebView component can not be run individually, it is recommended that you can create a Blazor app and build on the Blazor.

Comment: Hi, yes, I got it, and is working fine for my initial development. My main question is if I can deploy only the Blazor part, to a WebApp in Azure for example. So I can develop my multi-platform app (Android, iOS, Windows, Mac and Web Browser) in "one shot". Do you know if is it possible and how to do it? Thanks

Comment: You can deploy the Blazor part for the WebApp by using the Blazor not the Blazor Hybrid. In a Blazor Hybrid app, Razor components run natively on the device. Components render to an embedded Web View control through a local interop channel. So, components don't run in the browser, and WebAssembly isn't involved.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, I will verify how can I do that... Like, can I create two projects? One been only Blazor (for the web deploy) and another Hybrid, and use the Blazor only project somehow into it? Sorry for raising too many questions like this, I have a lot of experience in Windows and Web dev, but Blazor is a new area that I'm exploring now to help me migrating UWP and Web Projects. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, you can create two projects. As you mentioned that One been only Blazor (for the web deploy) and another Hybrid.